# Substring starting with a combination of digits till the next white space

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, string-matching

I have a very long string of around 2000 chars. The string is a join of segments with first two chars of each segment as the segment indicator.

Eg- '11xxxxx 12yyyy 14ddddd gghgfbddc 0876686589 SANDRA COLINS 201 STMONK CA'

Now I want to extract the segment with indicator 14.

I achieved this using:

```
str.split(' ').each do |substr|

  if substr.starts_with?('14')

     key = substr.slice(2,5).to_i 

     break

  end

end
```

I feel there should be a better way to do this. I am not able to find a more direct and one line solution for string matching in ruby. Please someone suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, because your example string shows letters, but your title says digits. Either way, this is a good task for a regular expression.

```
foo = '12yyyy 014dddd 14ddddd gghgfbddc'
bar = '12yyyy 014dddd 1499999 gghgfbddc'
baz = '12yyyy 014dddd 14a9B9z gghgfbddc'

foo[/\b14[a-zA-Z]+/] # => "14ddddd"
bar[/\b14\d+/] # => "1499999"
baz[/\b14\w+/] # => "14a9B9z"

foo[/\b14\S+/] # => "14ddddd"
bar[/\b14\S+/] # => "1499999"
baz[/\b14\S+/] # => "14a9B9z"
```

In the patterns:

- `\b` means word-break, so the pattern has to start at a transition between spaces or punctuation.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` means one or more letters.
- `\d+` means one or more digits.
- `\w+` means one or more of letters, digits and `'_'`. That is equivalent to the character set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.
- `\S+` means non-whitespace, which is useful if you want everything up to a space.

Which of those is appropriate for your use-case is really up to you to decide.